# Starting built in Apache server in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, webserver, apache-http-server, osx-mavericks

I'd like to start my apache server on my Mac running OS X (10.9) Mavericks. Here is what I did:

1. Goto terminal
2. sudo apachectl start
3. The server started without problem. But I got the following problem when I tried to open the localhost in web browser:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Here is my httpd.conf file in my /etc/apache2: (I didn't change anything here)

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all </Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Can anybody advise what could be the cause ? Thanks

Comment: Is it related to my Server application recently installed? I got the same problem when I start the website service in my Server application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I run into the same issue. After some goggling I figured that the main issue is that Apache runs as user **_www** whereas your files probably are under your own user. List the content of your webroot folder in Terminal (ls -l) to see the user and its group.

I found this link which provides a *"better solution"* instead of *"changing the owner"* or *"changing the permissions"*: http://francoisdeschenes.com/2013/02/26/enable-write-permissions-for-apache-built-into-mac-os-x

In short, do this (replace <dir> with the name of your folder):

```
sudo chmod -R +a '_www allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' <dir>
```

Of course, all the glory goes to Francois.

Comment: I don't know what I did. Then the website suddenly works. I guess it's because I uninstall the "Server" and reinstall it.Anyway, I think your answer should be correct. I'll definitely follow this instruction if I encounter this problem again. Thanks.

Comment: This solution seems to work well.